# Remove Duplicate content from file using python based on header

Tags: python, file

i am new to python i have to remove duplicate data based on some condition that is if
symb variable is match with same symb variable then remove the duplicate symb variable and associate data like( dtype,
iotype ,
bias ,
slpe  ,
unit   ,
max  ,
min  ,
client_no ,
path ,
ends) . here i am attach a file.

fil link below

[Download the file from here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nT3wnJ_I76XvIUNtAclJZhRl5XVA0z-e/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates method to remove duplicates from the file

```
import pandas as pd     # Import Pandas DF
input = "sample.txt"    # Input File
output = sample_original.txt    # output file
df = pd.read_csv(input, sep="\t or ,")    # Copy the files into the Dataframe \t is used for tab seperation , is used for comma seperation depends on how the text is spaced 
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)  # Drop the duplicates Using inplace = True modifies original file also if you do not want to do this drop the inplace option
df.to_csv(file_name_output, index=False) # Export the content without duplicates into a txt file.
```

I assume your file is a txt as I was able to import it into notepad

Here is the link to documentation of Pandas

[pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: This is not a csv file or excel file to remove duplicates.it is a .sym or any txt file. here i wrote based on same symb variable it will remove the duplicate content of that duplicate occurred value.

Comment: Yes as you told it is a .sym or any txt file


For importing any file you have to import it into a variable in python which is mostly a dataframe. This dataframe is like a matrix and has rows and columns and hence you can perform any operations fatser here

Comment: You can also import it into an array but that would become long and difficult